# Storybook/webpack does not load less styles from components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, less, storybook, monorepo

I'm trying to update a react components monorepo from storybook 5.3 and webpack 4.4 to storybook 6.5 and webpack 5.
After overcoming multiple hurdles, I am at the point where the storybook does run fine, but the styles from inside the components are not being loaded.

Here's my storybook/main.js

```js
const path = require("path")

module.exports = {
  framework: "@storybook/react",
  core: {
    builder: "webpack5",
  },
  stories: ["../stories/**/*.stories.tsx"], // all stories are .tsx files
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-knobs",
    "@storybook/addon-actions",
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "ts-loader",
          },
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "less-loader"],
      },
    );
    config.resolve.extensions.push(".tsx", ".ts");
    config.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve(__dirname, "../src"), path.resolve(__dirname, "../stories"));
    return config;
  },
};
```

storybook/package.json

```json
...
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/addon-styling": "^0.3.2",
    "@storybook/addons": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.16",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.23",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "@types/storybook__react": "^4.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "less": "^4.2.0",
    "less-loader": "^11.1.3",
    "shx": "^0.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.4",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
```

This is the way styles and components are being imported:

```
import { Button, PrimaryButton, SecondaryButton, TertiaryButton, Link } from "@our-component-lib/buttons";

import "@our-component-lib/buttons/src/style.less";

const story = storiesOf("Atoms @our-component-lib/buttons", module);

...
```

This project is also using lerna, which I'm not familiar with. The root package.json has all the same versions for the similar packages.
It's worth noting that no other changes have been made other than updating the main.js along with the packages. Webpack has also been updated and configured with all necessary changes going from v4 to v5. I am not getting any errors in console, just no css files loaded at all in the browser. So this has broken only from updating/making sure breaking changes are covered.

What could I be missing here?

I am running on:
node 18.16.1
npm 8.19.4
windows 10

I tried adding the [addon-styling package from storybook](https://storybook.js.org/recipes/less) and configuring it as such in the main.js
I also tried setting sideEffects to true for less files in main.js

```
test: /.less$/,
use: [...],
sideEffects: true
```

```js
addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-knobs",
    "@storybook/addon-actions",
    {
      name: "@storybook/addon-styling",
      options: {
        less: {
          implementation: require("less"),
        },
      },
    },
  ],
```